# How do I get the exact string stream from buffer?

Tags: node.js, encoding, utf-8, iconv

With the following code,

```
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
var msg = iconv.encode ('你好', 'gb18030');
console.log (msg);
```

I got

```
<Buffer c4 e3 ba c3>
```

Now, I need to get these bytes in binary. If I do a hexdump it should show as `c4 e3 ba c3`

So I tried `msg.toString ()`, `msg.toString ('binary')`, none of them works correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for exactly. But I assume, you want to create a readable stream from a buffer. In this case refer this [link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2681-turning-buffers-into-readable-streams-in-node-js.htm)

Comment: @A.I I want something that shows `c4 e3 ba c3` in hexdump

Comment: @A.I Just modified the question and changed stream into 'bytes'

Comment: Okay. You can directly access the binary data from the buffer using `msg[index]`